# How do I create a new object that already exists in another method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have an array `movieScedule` that include object Movie. In this movie object I have the price of the ticket.

Now I want to create a method that shows the most expensive ticket for the movie.

The method:

```
public Movie mostExpensive()
{
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```

Now I was thinking to create new movie object inside this method
and then for loop to run all over the movies in the array
and then another for loop to run from index 0 all over the movies and check each movie price by using `getMoviePrice()` method

In the end I wanted to declare the object movie that I created inside this method as the highest `moviePrice`
and then return (the movie)

Any idea? Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea - go for it!

Comment: I dont know how to do it thats the problem hehe

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: You only need one loop to find the highest price.

If Move is immutable, simply return the found object; else return a newly created copy of the found object.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume, you have a Movie class, like so:

```java
class Movie {
    private Double moviePrice;
}
```

Any you want to find the highest price, not the movie with the highest price.

```java
Movie mostExpensive() {
    Movie mostExpensiveMovie = null;

    for (Movie movie : movieScedule) {
        if (mostExpensiveMovie == null || //use for the first element
                // compare previous film price with current one
                movie.getMoviePrice() > mostExpensiveMovie.getMoviePrice()) {
            mostExpensiveMovie = movie;
        }
    }
    return mostExpensiveMovie; // return most expensive movie
}
```

This will be cheaper, no need to create new Movie instance.
If you want, this can also be achieved by java8 streams, check [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775518/java-stream-find-an-element-with-a-min-max-value-of-an-attribute).

```java
Optional<Movie> mostExpensiveMovie = Arrays.stream(movieScedule)
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getTicketPrice));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand you question corretly. Hopefully this is what you want. An easy way to obtain the most expensive ticket would be:

```
ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
//populate array list

public Movie getMostExpensiveTicket(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    Movie mostExpensive = movies.get(0); // not null save
    for (Movie movie : movies) {
        if (movie.getMoviePrice() > mostExpensive.getMoviePrice())
            mostExpensive = movie;
    }
    return mostExpensive;
}
```

Comment: Beri was faster and his answer is null save. So please use his approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or above, I would suggest taking advantage of java streams. It would look like this:

```
public static Movie mostExpesive(Movie[] MoviesSchedule) {
    Optional<Movie> maxPriceMovie = Stream.of(MoviesSchedule)
            .collect(Collectors.maxBy((a, b) -> a.price - b.price));
    return maxPriceMovie.get();
}
```