# Which is a good approach either to create an array of object or to create data members as an array?

Tags: java, arrays, function, optimization, constructor

I have used two approaches to solve the Question
Here, Both Works
But what i need to know is
Which will be the Best to do
Should I create an Array of Object
or
Should I create data members as an array ?

```
// Write a program in java to input and display the details of n number of students having roll, name and cgpa as data members. Also display the name of the student having lowest cgpa.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class _3 {
    int n;
    int roll[];
    String name[];
    float cgpa[];

    _3(int n, int roll[], String name[], float cgpa[]) {
        this.roll = new int[n];
        this.name = new String[n];
        this.cgpa = new float[n];
        this.n = n;
        this.roll = roll;
        this.name = name;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the No. of Students to store data of: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        int roll[] = new int[num];
        String name[] = new String[num];
        float cgpa[] = new float[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Detail of Student : " + i);
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Roll: ");
            roll[i] = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("CGPA: ");
            cgpa[i] = sc.nextFloat();
        }
        _3 obj = new _3(num, roll, name, cgpa);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Student Details are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            obj.display(i, name[i], roll[i], cgpa[i]);
        }
        sc.close();

        int min = obj.lowest(cgpa);
        System.out.println("\nThe Student with Lowest CGPA is: ");
        System.out.println("Name: " + name[min] + "\nRoll: " + roll[min] + "\nCGPA: " + cgpa[min]);

    }

    void display(int i, String name, int roll, float cgpa) {
        System.out.println("Detail of Student: " + i);
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\nRoll: " + roll + "\nCGPA: " + cgpa);
    }

    int lowest(float arr[]) {
        int min = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < arr[min]) {
                min = i;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Here, I have created Data Members as an Array

```
//// Write a program in java to input and display the details of n number of students having roll, name and cgpa as data members. Also display the name of the student having lowest cgpa.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student_3 {


    int roll;
    String name;
    float cgpa;

    Student_3(int roll, String name, float cgpa) {
        this.roll = roll;
        this.name = name;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the No. Of Students to store the Data of: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        Student_3 student[] = new Student_3[num];
        int roll;
        String name;
        float cgpa;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Details of Student No: " + (i + 1));
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            sc.nextLine();
            name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Roll No.: ");
            roll = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("CGPA: ");
            cgpa = sc.nextFloat();

            student[i] = new Student_3(roll, name, cgpa);
        }
        sc.close();

        // Displaying the Detail of Students
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            student[i].display(i, student[i]);
        }

        // Lowest CGPA
        student[0].lowest_cgpa(student);
    }

    void display(int i, Student_3 student) {
        System.out.println("Details of Student No: " + (i + 1));
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\nRoll: " + student.roll + "\nCGPA: " + student.cgpa);


    }

    void lowest_cgpa(Student_3 student[]) {
        int min = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
            if (student[i].cgpa < student[min].cgpa) {
                min = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Student Details of lowest CGPA Holder is:");
        display(min, student[min]);
    }
}
```

Here, I have created Array of Object
Both program runs fine
but
Which will be the Best Approach to do ???

Comment: A 'class' (as in school) is a collection of students. Therefore the class (as in Java) should contain  `Collection<Student>`. Avoid parallel arrays like the plague

Comment: Questions seeking opinions are regarded as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. However, the preference of avoiding parallel arrays in favor of use of Objects of a class that glue together is widely regarded as better Object-Oriented Design is so strong and common advice.

Answer (score 1):

Maintaining a group of parallel arrays is annoying and troublesome.

If using an [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language like Java, you might as well use objects.

Define a class to represent each student. If the purpose of this class is to transparently communicate shallowly-[immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) data, then make that class a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

```java
record Student ( String name , double grade ) {}
```

Instantiate the student objects, and collect. You can use an array for this, but generally better to use the [Java Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

```java
List< Student > classroom = new ArrayList<>();
class.add( new Student ( "Alice" , 3.3d ) ) ;
class.add( new Student ( "Bob" , 2.8d ) ) ;
class.add( new Student ( "Carol" , 3.1d ) ) ;
```

To find the lowest, you could loop.

```java
Student lowestGrade = null ;
for( Student student : class ) 
{
    if ( Objects.isNull( lowestGrade ) {
        lowestGrade = student ;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if ( student.grade() < lowestGrade.grade() ) 
        {
            lowestGrade = student ;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This code ignores the issue of students tied for lowest grade.

In more advanced Java, use streams, a `Comparator`, and a method reference. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36775518/642706).

```java
Student lowestGrade =
        classroom
                .stream ( )
                .min ( Comparator.comparing ( Student :: grade ) )
                .orElse ( null );
```

No need for `display` method. The `toString` method implemented implicitly in a record does basically what you want.

Result:

> lowestGrade = Student[name=Bob, grade=2.8]

For clarity, separate your `main` method outside of your `Student` class. Make a class named something like `Main` or `App`. And move the user-interface code into its own method.